# Sequelize CLI "Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0"

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am trying to dynamically load configuration to perform migration with sequelize-cli.

this is my script:

```
 sequelize --config ./sequelize-systemdb.js  --env systemdb db:migrate
```

this is the config file:

```
module.exports = {
  "config": {
    "username": USER,
    "password": PASSWORD,
    "database": DBNAME,
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "pool": {
      "max": 5,
      "min": 0,
      "acquire": 30000,
      "idle": 10000
    }
  },
  "models-path": path.resolve(`./models`),
  "seeders-path": path.resolve(`./seeders/systemdb`),
  "migrations-path": path.resolve(`./migrations/systemdb`)
};
```

I can see that the correct file is loaded, however, I am getting an error:

ERROR: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0
although dialect is obviously supplied.

no matter what I tried, still issue persist.
Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

You named the configuration as `config` but for the call you indicated the configuration `systemdb`. Either rename configuration field or indicate another config name in the command line.

```js
module.exports = {
  "systemdb": {
    "username": USER,
    "password": PASSWORD,
    "database": DBNAME,
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "pool": {
      "max": 5,
      "min": 0,
      "acquire": 30000,
      "idle": 10000
    }
  },
  "models-path": path.resolve(`./models`),
  "seeders-path": path.resolve(`./seeders/systemdb`),
  "migrations-path": path.resolve(`./migrations/systemdb`)
};
```

OR

```bash
 sequelize --config ./sequelize-systemdb.js  --env config db:migrate
```